# Find similar items and order by common tags count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I searched through similar questions but the solutions were for different situations with different tables structures :(

I need to get the list of design_id with similar tags, ordered by entries having the most common tags count first

Tables structures:

```
shop_tags (tag_id, tag_name)
shop_tags_link (tag_id, design)
shop_tshirts (design_id, article_id)
```

Let's say I have 4 designs

```
design_id 1 tags = red, blue
design_id 2 tags = black, grey
design_id 3 tags = yellow, green
design_id 4 tags = white, red, black
design_id 5 tags = red
```

The input is an array of designs ID :

```
$input = array("1", "2");
```

I need to find designs with similar tags and sort them by the common tags count (desc), so if the input is designs 1 and 2 we're looking for designs with tags "red, blue, black, grey" which would give the following result in this order :

`design 4, design 5`  (excluding the original input designs of course)

Finally, instead of returning the designs ID, I need to find the corresponding article_id from table shop_tshirts with the matching design. What is the best way to do this? Should I do a separate query or another INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating what we have to work with, so that the solution is more obvious:

```
+-----------+    +-----------------+    +--------------+
| shop_tags |    | shop_tags_links |    | shop_tshirts |
+-----------+    +-----------------+    +--------------+
| tag_id    |----| tag_id          |  /-| design_id    |
| tag_name  |    | design_id       |-/  | article_id   |
+-----------+    +-----------------+    +--------------+

design_id 1 tags = red, blue
design_id 2 tags = black, grey
design_id 3 tags = yellow, green
design_id 4 tags = white, red, black
design_id 5 tags = red

+-----------+   +-----------------+   +--------------+
| shop_tags |   | shop_tags_links |   | shop_tshirts |
+-----------+   +-----------------+   +--------------+
| 1 red     |   |   1  1          |   | 1  ?         |
| 2 blue    |   |   2  1          |   | 2  ?         |
| 3 black   |   |   3  2          |   | 3  ?         |
| 4 grey    |   |   4  2          |   | 4  ?         |
| 5 yellow  |   |   5  3          |   | 5  ?         |
| 6 green   |   |   6  3          |    
| 7 white   |   |   7  4          |   
|           |   |   1  4          |   
                |   3  4          |   
                |   1  5          |
```

> "find designs with similar tags and sort them by the common tags count (desc)", 
>   so if the input is designs 1 and 2 we're looking for designs with tags "red, blue, black, grey" which would give the following result in this order :
>
> design 4, design 5 (excluding the original input designs of course)"

This should get you pointed in the right direction.  This is off the top of my head and untested, so it probably needs a little tweaking, but it should cover the main concepts.

```
select count(b.tag_id) as mysort, b.design_id, c.article_id
from shop_tags_links as a, shop_tags_links as b inner join shop_tshirts as c on b.design_id=c.design_id
where 
    a.design_id IN (?,?) AND
    a.tag_id=b.tag_id AND
    b.design_id NOT IN(?,?) 
group by b.design_id
order by mysort desc
```